# Unable to drop a column that I used to explode an array

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

To preface, I am using `pyspark==2.4.5`.

When reading from a json file, which can be found here: https://filebin.net/53rhhigep2zpqdga, I need to explode the data, I also have no need for `data` after exploding and I have no need of `statistics` as well.

```py
spark= SparkSession.builder.master('local[2]').appName("createDataframe")\
        .getOrCreate()
json_data = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json(file_name)
json_data = json_data.withColumn("data_values", F.explode_outer("data"))\
        .drop("data", "statistics")
```

Below you will see the schema and the top 5 rows of `json_data`

```sh
root
 |-- data_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data_values                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2019-02-20, [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]]                                   |
|[2019-02-21, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:06:00]]]|
|[2019-02-22, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:06:00]]]|
|[2019-02-23, [[1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-23T00:16:00]]]                                                                                                         |
|[2019-02-24, [[1, 0, 1, 1, 2019-02-24T00:03:00], [1, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-24T00:04:00]]]                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now to get the data as I desire, I perform the queries below.

```py
newData = json_data\
   .withColumn("events", F.explode(json_data.data_values.events))\
   .withColumn("date", json_data.data_values.date)
newData.printSchema()
newData.show(3)
finalData = newData.drop("data_values")
finalData.show(6)
```

Above you see that I am creating a column called `data_values` that explodes my incoming json data. Then I create columns to extract the events and date from `data_values`. Below you will see how the schema looks, as well as the top 5 rows.

```sh
root
 |-- data_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- events: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------+
|data_values                                                                                                                                               |events                           |date      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------+
|[2019-02-20, [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]]                                   |[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00]|2019-02-20|
|[2019-02-20, [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]]                                   |[0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00]|2019-02-20|
|[2019-02-20, [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]]                                   |[0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]|2019-02-20|
|[2019-02-21, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:06:00]]]|[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00]|2019-02-21|
|[2019-02-21, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:06:00]]]|[0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00]|2019-02-21|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

When I have the dataframe that I desire I then try to drop `data_values` but I get this error:

```sh
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: _gen_alias_25#25
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReference(BoundAttribute.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.$anonfun$bindReferences$1(BoundAttribute.scala:96)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReferences(BoundAttribute.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:482)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.doProduce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:455)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:629)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:689)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3482)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3472)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3468)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2788)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:334)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find _gen_alias_25#25 in [data_values#5]
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(BoundAttribute.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
```

The schema of `newData` has the fields that I want, but executing `newData.show(3)` results in the error above.

```sh
root
 |-- events: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

I have tried creating a new dataframe after dropping `data_values` and then running .show() but I still get the same issue. I'm guessing that for some reason, the new columns I created are still referencing `data_values` so maybe the way I am creating these columns is wrong?

I have tried finding people who have the same issue online but it seems as if this is not a common issue. As there is not much info on the `gen_alias` error.

Comment: COuld you please just add your data frame 'json_data' top 5 rows ?

Comment: yes give me one second!

Comment: As you creating data frame from JSON file so I can not create data frame manually here but there is one workaround for this: instead of deleting the column just select only the required column for your result.

Comment: I get the same error attempting that as well. I can post the json data if you'd like?

Comment: could you please link 5 rows of json in file?

Comment: I included a link to the file in the top of the post

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using spark 2.4.3

**point 1: update path**

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> json_data = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json("/home/maheshpersonal/stack.json")
>>> json_data.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[2019-02-20, [[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]], [2019-02-21, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:06:00]]], [2019-02-22, [[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:06:00]]], [2019-02-23, [[1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-23T00:16:00]]], [2019-02-24, [[1, 0, 1, 1, 2019-02-24T00:03:00], [1, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-24T00:04:00]]]]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Point:2 check the schema**

```
>>> json_data.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

**Point3: exploding the data columns**

```
>>> json_data_1 = json_data.withColumn("data_values", F.explode_outer("data"))
>>> json_data_1.printSchema ()
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- events: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- active: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

**Point4: selecting the column as per requirement**

```
 >>> newData = json_data_1.withColumn("events", json_data_1.data_values.events).withColumn("date", json_data_1.data_values.date)

 >>> newData.show()
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
    |                data|         data_values|              events|      date|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
    |[[2019-02-20, [[0...|[2019-02-20, [[0,...|[[0, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-20|
    |[[2019-02-20, [[0...|[2019-02-21, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-21|
    |[[2019-02-20, [[0...|[2019-02-22, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-22|
    |[[2019-02-20, [[0...|[2019-02-23, [[1,...|[[1, 3, 1, 1, 201...|2019-02-23|
    |[[2019-02-20, [[0...|[2019-02-24, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 1, 201...|2019-02-24|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

**point5 : dropping the data column from dataframe**

```
>>> newData_v1 = newData.drop(newData.data)
>>> newData_v1.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|         data_values|              events|      date|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|[2019-02-20, [[0,...|[[0, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-20|
|[2019-02-21, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-21|
|[2019-02-22, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 201...|2019-02-22|
|[2019-02-23, [[1,...|[[1, 3, 1, 1, 201...|2019-02-23|
|[2019-02-24, [[1,...|[[1, 0, 1, 1, 201...|2019-02-24|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

**Point6: drop data_values column from newData_v1**

```
>>> finalDataframe = newData_v1.drop(newData_v1.data_values)
>>> finalDataframe.show(truncate = False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|events                                                                                                                                      |date      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|[[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]]                                   |2019-02-20|
|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-21T00:06:00]]|2019-02-21|
|[[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:03:00], [0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-22T00:04:00], [1, 2, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:05:00], [1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-22T00:06:00]]|2019-02-22|
|[[1, 3, 1, 1, 2019-02-23T00:16:00]]                                                                                                         |2019-02-23|
|[[1, 0, 1, 1, 2019-02-24T00:03:00], [1, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-24T00:04:00]]                                                                      |2019-02-24|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Learning from this is always use a new data frame to store the transformation. please check if it helps you :)

Comment: I will try your solution, however, could you see if it works when exploding the data to create the `events` column like how I have it in my post?

Comment: but you haven't added the dropping column command for data_values column

Comment: I apologize I just noticed, I have updated that. Also, your approach works when my `events` column is in the form that you have it, but not in the way I desire to have it.

Comment: Okay ... let me try your approach even though the spark document suggests the use of the new data frame after every transformation...I am still not able to see the drop() function for data_values from data frame

Comment: I misunderstood you, I have added how i drop `data_values` as well as how I create the events column. I am also creating new data frames after using drop() and still getting the error

Comment: Is it working or not? which spark version are you using?

Comment: Currently, it is not working. I am using `pyspark==2.4.5`

Comment: It seems to me, this is a spark version problem because I am able to execute your code and getting expected result

Comment: I downgraded to pyspark==2.4.3 and performed your execution and it still breaks. May I see your newest output with the double array in `events` expended to a 1-D array?

Comment: Copy paste in some editor to see the actual output 
>>> finalData.show(5,truncate = False)
+---------------------------------+----------+
|events                           |date      |
+---------------------------------+----------+
|[0, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:00:00]|2019-02-20|
|[0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:01:00]|2019-02-20|
|[0, 2, 1, 0, 2019-02-20T00:02:00]|2019-02-20|
|[1, 0, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:03:00]|2019-02-21|
|[0, 1, 1, 0, 2019-02-21T00:04:00]|2019-02-21|
+---------------------------------+----------+
only showing top 5 rows

Comment: Yeah that's the output I need... which java version are you using?

Comment: Java -version : openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
Now you can also accept the answer as it is giving you the desired output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213326/discussion-between-mahesh-gupta-and-frlzjosh).